# Linux command to run a shell script upon receipt of any input

Tags: linux, bash, grep, stderr

I need to monitor `stderr` for a certain error message, and when it is detected, run a shell script.

Current idea is to pipe `stderr` to `grep`, and filter for the message. I would pipe `grep`'s output to some program that would run my script upon receipt of *any* user input.

Alternatively, if I could make `grep` output a specific command-line option parameter, I could presumably pipe that directly to my shell script.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: What should happen to the output generating command once the error message is detected? Should the command be stopped? Should it continue to run? If so, what should happen if the error message is detected a second time?

Comment: The shell script restarts the output generating command

Answer (score 0):

### I would like to recommend inotifywait.

- Monitor stderr-log.txt for changes.
- Read file and grep the stderr message.
- Call another script if error message is found

  `while:;do
     inotifywait -q -e modify ./stderr-log.txt > /dev/null
    if cat stderr-log.txt | grep -q <error message>; then 
     <do something here..>
    fi
  done`

Comment: Thanks but I can't find `stderr-log.txt` anywhere. Am I missing a step to redirect `stderr` to this file?

Comment: Hi, stderr-log.txt was an example, change this to the file you want to monitor.